# Changing background color of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

On canvas, I have a rectangle that has white as default color and I want to change its color by using a color picker that stores the color in a textbox. If user types in a color name, value or the input color picker it should change.

I don't understand why my code doesn't work at all. Could you help me?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 60;
canvas.height = 400;

let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

let start_background_color = "white";

context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
context.fillStyle = start_background_color;
context.fillRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

function change_background_color() {
  let color = document.getElementById('colorInputColor').value;
  //document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.getElementById('colorInputText').value = color;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="colorInputText">
<input type="color" class="color-picker" id="colorInputColor">
<input type="button" id="colorButton" value="Click to Change Color" onclick="change_background_color">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when calling the function change_background_color you have to use parentheseis too like this

```
<input type="button" id="colorButton" value="Click to Change Color" onclick="change_background_color()">
```